# How to get audio working on Debian

Tags: linux, audio, debian

I'm running debian linux in dual-boot with windows 10 and everything works properly but the audio. These are my audio devices:

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

Now, I've tried no unmute master from alsamixer, but it doesn't work so I'm asking you all how to get my audio to work.

Comment: (1) Include output from `aplay -l` so we can see if the drivers work and recognize both devices. (2) Look at `dmesg` after boot to see if there are any suspicious audio-related error messages. (3) What does `pavucontrol` say about available output devices?

Comment: It looks like you may have posted the question as an unregistered user, then registered another account and posted the answer.  Be aware that both accounts exist and you'll encounter problems if you intermix them.  For example, you'll be able to accept your own answer in another day, but you will need to do that under the account used to create the question.  You can also freely edit your own posts but for your protection, it must be done under the account used to write it.  You will be able to comment within your own thread but at this rep, it must be with the associated account. (cont'd)

Comment: You can simplify life by merging the two accounts.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts).  For reference, the question account is http://superuser.com/users/684171/domenico and the answer account is http://superuser.com/users/684462/domenico-procopio.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the audio with pavucontrol, I just raised the volume

Comment: If you've been using only the new account, you might have missed the comment on the old one.  Just wanted to make sure you were aware of it.  :-)